# Parsing a full date (date and hour) string to date causes exception

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'ma acquiring a date from SQLITE database which is like: 2012-05-07 20:59:45

Trying to execute this code, but it fails

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date = formatter.parse("2012-05-07 20:59:45");
```

How do I do that correctly then? Also tried `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: The format string used for parsing has to match the expected input

Comment: You want the format it is for Parsing.  The 1 of 2012 is not the - of dd- is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`?

Comment: geez, of course. Sorry, my brain is washed out after a day of work :/

Comment: If you're not interested in the time itself, you can convert the Date to a Calendar object, and zero out the hours, minutes and seconds as well (or just use joda-time which has methods to do this sort of thing for you)

Answer (score 0):

You try as below,

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = formatter.parse("2012-05-07 20:59:45");
```